# how to connect a shared MongoDB cluster using java code?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I setup a shared cluster on local host with 3 replica set, and running mongos on default port. How can I connect to shared cluster using Java API.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the Java Mongo Driver (http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-java-driver/#getting-started-with-java-driver). Specifically, for your case, you'll need to create a mongoClient seeded with the hosts and ports of your mongos (or mongos-es? read more here http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/MongoClient.html).

```
// for a sharded cluster setup with two mongos running on 27017 and 27018
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(Arrays.asList(new ServerAddress("localhost", 27017),
                                      new ServerAddress("localhost", 27018));

DB db = mongoClient.getDB( "mydb" );
```

If you're planning on building a more complicated application on top of MongoDB, I'd highly suggest looking at Morphia (https://github.com/mongodb/morphia) as well.